# How to calculate in javascript with %

Tags: javascript, excel

I've got some Excel formulas. Something like this:

```
13,7%/(33.3%/6.0%)*100%
```

How can I do this in Javascript?

Thanx in advance!

Freek

Comment: @pimvdb No it doesn't. `100+10%` usually isn't evaluated to `100.1` but `110`. Personally I don't like that kind of calculation at all and always switch to real numbers.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: My bad, but your example returns `10010.00%` in Excel.

Comment: What I said was based on how my old calculator handled it. Excel seems to be even more strange. Just checked and my new calculator calculated it as `100.1`. So it seems that adding percentages to real numbers is very dependent on the program.

Comment: well it makes sense: 100 + 10% == 100 + 10/100 = 100.1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just treat the numbers as decimals instead of percentages

```
var x = .137/(.333/.06)*100
```

Then format the result with a % to display it.

Comment: Shouldn't that last number be `1`, and not `100`?

Comment: @pimvdb That comment made my day

Answer (score 1):

[Move the decimal point two places to the left](http://www.mathsisfun.com/converting-percents-decimals.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a regexp replacing all occurences with `/100`.

```
var str = "13.7% + 50%/3%",
    regexp = /([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)\%/;

while(regexp.test(str)) str = str.replace(regexp, "($1/100)")
// "(13.7/100) + (50/100)/(3/100)"
```